# jsPDF Library not exporting Cyrillic letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I am trying to export data into PDF from a React project using JS. (I tried other libraries as well) so I am using jsPDF to create the pdf and it works fine until I try to export something in Cyrillic.

```
async function exportDataToPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    // Load the font file as a binary string
    const fontUrl = "../../../assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf";
    const fontData = await fetch(fontUrl).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
    const fontArray = new Uint8Array(fontData);
    const fontString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.from(fontArray));

    // Add the font to the virtual file system
    doc.addFileToVFS("Roboto-Regular.ttf", fontString);

    // Add the font to the document
    doc.addFont("Roboto-Regular.ttf", "Roboto", "normal");

    // Set the font
    doc.setFont("Roboto");

    // Set font size and add text
    doc.setFontSize(16);
    doc.text('In english', 10, 10);
    doc.text('На български', 10, 20);

    // Save the PDF
    doc.save('Планирано производство.pdf');
}
```

I tried importing the font this way, but it won't find it. It finds other files in the assets folder.

```
import RobotoRegular from "../../../assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf";
```

Then I tried to add the path in the function as shown in the code and it did read it, the font changed to Cyrillic, but it still won't read Cyrillic letters.

```
const fontUrl = "../../../assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf";
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix it using a base64 converted font. I converted the code and put it in a font folder that I exported. In my component, I imported it and set it as a font. I hope you find it helpful as there aren't many simple solutions on the internet!

**Links:**

jsPDF [documentation](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF?tab=readme-ov-file#use-of-unicode-characters--utf-8) on loading fonts.

jsPDF [online tool](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html) to convert .ttf to base64

Here is the updated code:

```
async function exportDataToPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    // *** Font Embedding ***
    doc.addFileToVFS('Roboto-Regular.ttf', robotoFontBase64);
    doc.addFont('Roboto-Regular.ttf', 'Roboto', 'normal'); 
    doc.setFont('Roboto');

    // *** Text Output ***
    doc.setFontSize(16);
    doc.text('In english', 10, 10);
    doc.text('На български', 10, 20);

    // Save the PDF
    doc.save('Планирано производство.pdf');
}
```